# How do I add text describing the code into a Python source file?

Tags: python

When writing code in Python, how can you write something next to it that explains what the code is doing, but which doesn't affect the code?

Comment: I suggest that you learn the basics of programming before you start to write code...

Comment: Writing code is the best way to learn.

Comment: @seanmonstar: I totally agree, but not before knowing the very basics such as commenting, you know what I mean.

Comment: @Lawand: When I've taught people programming, I've always started with them sitting in front of a text editor. The learned concepts stick better if you've used them (and likely used them wrong, so you won't do it again)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're talking about [comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Comments_and_docstrings)?

There are plain comments, which start with `#`:

```
return sys.stdin.readline()       # This is a comment
```

And also Docstrings, which document modules, classes, methods and functions:

```
def getline():
    """This is a docstring"""
    return sys.stdin.readline()
```

Unlike many other languages, Python does not have a multiline comment syntax (though docstrings can be multiline).

Comment: You might want to point out that  you can't  place triple-quoted strings anywhere you want. Docstrings can only exist at certain places in the code.

Comment: -1 for not making clear the important distinction between comments (how you do something) and docstrings (what the code is supposed to do).

Comment: @nikow: I can't understand the distinction you're making between how the code works and what the code does.

Comment: @S.Lott: I assume your personal statement is meant as a question? Comments should describe implementation details, docstrings describe the API (at least in an ideal world with non-leaky abstractions). Just describing the docstring syntax without any info on how to use them proberly is probably not very helpful for the OP.

Comment: @Bryan: You can place strings, quoted in a way you prefer, almost anywhere.

Comment: @kaizer: You are not seriously suggesting to use string expressions instead of comments?

Comment: @nikow: I was primarily correcting something that was outright false. Triple-quoted strings provide multi-line "comment" function for quickly commenting out code, so yes, I've used that, but more permanent comments are usually written with comment syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Write a comment? Python comments start with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

You mean comments? Use the # character before your comment.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Source_Documentation_and_Comments

```
# This is a comment
print("Hello comment!")
```